# MySQL Join from multiple options to select one value

Tags: sql, mysql, select, join

I am putting together a nice little database for adding values to options, all these are setup through a map (Has and Belongs to Many) table, because many options are pointing to a single value.

So I am trying to specify 3 option.ids and a single id in a value table - four integers to point to a single value. Three tables. And I am running into a problem with the WHERE part of the statement, because if multiple values share an option there are many results. And I need just a single result.

```
SELECT value.id, value.name FROM value
 LEFT JOIN (option_map_value, option_table)
 ON (value.id = option_map_value.value_id AND option_map_value.option_table_id = option_table.id)
 WHERE option_table.id IN (5, 2, 3) AND value.y_axis_id = 16;
```

The problem with the statement seems to be the IN on the WHERE clause. If one of the numbers are different in the IN() part, then there are multiple results - which is not good.

I have tried DISTINCT, which again works if there is one result, but returns many if there is many. The closest we have gotten to is adding a count - to return to value with the most options at the top.

So is there a way to do the WHERE to be more specific. I cannot break it out into option_table.id = 5 AND option_table.id = 2 - because that one fails. But can the WHERE clause be more specifc?

Maybe it is me being pedantic, but I would like to be able to return just the single result, instead of a count of results... Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The problem with the statement seems to be the IN on the WHERE clause. If one of the numbers are different in the IN() part, then there are multiple results - which is not good.  I have tried DISTINCT, which again works if there is one result, but returns many if there is many. The closest we have gotten to is adding a count - to return to value with the most options at the top.

You were very close, considering the `DISTINCT`:

```
    SELECT v.id, 
           v.name 
      FROM VALUE v
 LEFT JOIN OPTION_MAP_VALUE omv ON omv.value_id = v.id
 LEFT JOIN OPTION_TABLE ot ON ot.id = omv.option_table_id
     WHERE ot.id IN (5, 2, 3) 
       AND v.y_axis_id = 16
  GROUP BY v.id, v.name
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
```

You were on the right track, but needed to use `GROUP BY` instead in order to be able to use the HAVING clause to count the DISTINCT list of values.

**Caveat emptor:**
The `GROUP BY/HAVING COUNT` version of the query is dependent on your data model having a composite key, unique or primary, defined for the two columns involved (`value_id` and `option_table_id`). If this is not in place, the database will not stop duplicates being added. If duplicate rows are possible in the data, this version can return false positives because a `value_id` could have 3 associations to the `option_table_id` 5 - which would satisfy the `HAVING COUNT(*) = 3`.

### Using JOINs:

A safer, though more involved, approach is to join onto the table that can have multiple options, as often as you have criteria:

```
  SELECT v.id, 
         v.name 
    FROM VALUE v
    JOIN OPTION_MAP_VALUE omv ON omv.value_id = v.id
    JOIN OPTION_TABLE ot5 ON ot5.id = omv.option_table_id
                         AND ot5.id = 5
    JOIN OPTION_TABLE ot2 ON ot2.id = omv.option_table_id
                         AND ot2.id = 2
    JOIN OPTION_TABLE ot3 ON ot3.id = omv.option_table_id
                         AND ot3.id = 3
   WHERE v.y_axis_id = 16
GROUP BY v.id, v.name
```

Comment: Thanks Mr. Ponies. Is that the only way? There is no way to specify the ot.id separately in the WHERE clause?

Comment: Thanks so much OMGPonies.

I have finally got around to testing this out and the JOIN section of the answer fails - It returns no results. If I remove two of the option_table JOINS then it works but returns many results.

I tried it with different data to only two option_table JOINs and same thing. If there is one JOIN works fine, any more and it returns more results.

Tried LEFT JOIN, but of course that returned the additional row.

I have no ideas left. Do you have any more tricks up your sleeve?